# Hibernate save entity with existing Id

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-insert, h2, in-memory-database

I am creating a CRUD application using Servlets and Hibernate.

When I try to save a new entity using save(), then Hibernate executes the SQL Update query and not Insert. The entity already contains the generated Id (UUID) and as I understand it, it searches for this entity in the database (h2 in-memory) and does not find it. How to properly save an entity in the database if the id has already been generated.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MATCH")
public class Match implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "MATCH_ID")
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Player playerOne;

    @ManyToOne
    private Player playerTwo;

    @ManyToOne
    private Player winner;


    @Transient
    private int[] score = new int[2];

    public Match() {

    }

        //getters and setters
}




   public void executePost(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try (Session session = DBHandler.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            UUID MatchUuid = UUID.fromString(servletRequest.getParameter("match-uuid"));  
            currentMatchService = CurrentMatchService.getInstance(); //service stores current matches in the app's memory
            currentMatch = currentMatchService.getMatch(MatchUuid);
            currentMatch.setWinner(currentMatch.getPlayerOne()); //player One set like winner just for test
            session.save(currentMatch);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Hello, please share the entity as a formatted code snippet. Especially the definition of id field.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Please also share the code part where you actually persist the entity.

Comment: id = UUID.randomUUID();

when I create entity.

Comment: OK. So you have another code in use when you create a new entity, right? And what is actually wrong? Are you getting any SQL errors? Please share it as well.

Comment: ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKFTYLRNBHDEROXV82GJU98UYJE: PUBLIC.MATCH FOREIGN KEY(PLAYERONE_PLAYER_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.PLAYER(PLAYER_ID) (X'7a4d091de8cb46a5b0149bbf0111446f')"; SQL statement:
/* update com.kharizma.tennisscoreboard.models.Match */ update MATCH set playerOne_PLAYER_ID=?, playerTwo_PLAYER_ID=?, winner_PLAYER_ID=? where MATCH_ID=? [23506-200]

Comment: Does the player entity you are using exist in the database? Because the error shows a constraint violation on the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question you want to persist the entity in the database without letting Hibernate generate an identifier for you. To accomplish it you  can use following code:

If the entity with the id already exists in the database and should be updated - please use:

```
session.merge(myEntity); // myEntity contains the id
```

If it's a new entity and should be inserted - please use:

```
UUUID id = UUID.randomUUID(); // new id will be generated
myEntity.setId(id);
session.persist(myEntity);
```

Comment: The entity does not exist in the database yet, but the error is the same.
I tried persist(), but the error is the same. And I don't understand what's a problem.

Comment: Why it says that hibernate uses SQL statement  with update, not insert?

Comment: You can activate the SQL logs in the system.properties hibernate.show_sql=true to get more information.